Defining a new simplicial complex using two pure simplicial complexes
In one of my projects, I have came across a simplicial complex defined in the following way:
Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be two pure simplicial complexes of dimension $n$. Define a simplicial complex $K$ with the vertex set $V(K) = \{(x_1,x_2) : x_i \in V(K_i)\}$ and the facets $\{\{(x_0,y_{\sigma(0)}),\ldots,(x_n, y_{\sigma(n)})\} : \sigma \in S_{n+1}, \{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}\ \text{and} \ \{y_0,\ldots,y_n\}\ \text{are facets of} \ K_1\ \text{and}\ K_2\}.$
I want to know whether the above definition is already in the literature? If yes, then what combinatorial properties of these simplicial complexes  are known?
Note: This is not the product of $K_1$ and $K_2$. When $K_1$ and $K_2$ are $n$-simplices, then $K$ is a chessboard complex.

Unless I am mistaken, this appears to be an equivalent definition (using facets instead of all faces) of the join of two simplicial complexes. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)#Abstract_simplicial_complexes.

The vertex set here is the product of the vertex sets of $K_1$ and $K_2$. In the join, the vertex set is the union of the vertex sets.

Ah, you are correct --- this is very different from the join. And, despite its apparent similarity with the categorical product of simplicial complexes, I see that is not, based on your remark about chessboard complexes. Thanks!
